# Subsurf Modifier artifacts

Tags: modifiers, geometry, edges

So I was messing with Subsurf modifier to create a certain sword and then some weird artifacts began to appear (cape-like). I've tried adjusting the Crease, but couldn't achive what I wanted. Basicly, what I whant is the as on the screens, but wo any artifacts :)
[image]
[image]
Also, here's the .blend file, cause I assume I didn't make myselt 100% clear.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0hdCv37NrtVMXU4eFB2MFFlMGM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some non-manifold geometry in your mesh.

[image]

There is a large ngon overlapping the other polygons.

[image]

Here is how to fix it:

1. Select the large ngons

   - you can either do this manually which is faster in this case since there are only 2 ngons or you could use a selection tool.
   - Select -> Select Faces by sides: greater than 4
2. Delete them: <kbd>x</kbd> -> Faces (<kbd>3</kbd>)
3. Select all geometry in the mesh: <kbd>A</kbd>
4. now to fix the holes: Mesh -> Clean Up -> Fill Holes

   [image]

---

This fixes part of your problem. The other problem is the creasing. To fix this I would either use edge loops instead of creases or crease all continuous parts of the mesh rather than just single edges.

[image]

Comment: yeah, I should've found those ngons myself, thanx for the answer :) didn't quite solve the problem with the capes above, but I think I'll just mess with the topology (because creases also didn't have any affect)