# Subdivision surface modifier error

Tags: subdivision-surface

[image: blender screenshot]

I'm having issues with my object with the subdivision surface modifier. I can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong. It creates overlapping faces that I can't edit.

Comment: You probably have ngons around the "hole". You need to isolate it with proper quad mesh part.

Comment: Related [1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7763/subsurf-modifier-artifacts)  and [2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29219/subsurf-modifier-creating-mesh-irregularities)

Answer (score 2):

You are probably in this situation:

[image]

The problem is due to the ngons surrounding the hole: they are not easily processed by the subsurface modifier, so you need to change them into quads.

[image]

- Enter edit mode
- Set mesh select mode to "face" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Select the ngons
- Triangulate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>
- Make quads <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> (reselect and redo it as needed)
- There is some glitches at the corner
- So surround the hole <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>
- And adjust the position of the surrounding section