# Shading artifacts caused by boolean modifier

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, mesh, modifiers, shaders

I tried applying a boolean modifier so I could make some holes inside a mesh, but the result was horrible shading. I've tried smooth lighting and an edge split modifier with sharp edges, but still nothing so far. I even added a new knife cut near the ends so it wouldn't be as noticeable. It's really bugging me, please help! Split concave edges just made a bunch of triangles with even worse shading.
[image: Boolean shading problem][image: Boolean shading problem 2][image: Edit mode]

[image: closeup][image: wireframe]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13554/applied-boolean-modifier-leaving-shading-artifacts-with-flat-shading https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84455/smooth-shading-sub-surface-distorted-render

Comment: That first link was pretty useful, but still doesn't solve my problem, as I already used the edge split modifier, and I can't make a triangle fan out of my cylinder. Also I didn't use the subsurface modifier

Comment: try auto smooth in the vertex tab

Comment: A picture of the wireframe, or sample file will shed more light. One fears the boolean modifier may have naffed up your topology.

Comment: @atek What would be the point in doing that? I already have an edge modifier, auto smoothing does nothing more than my sharp edges

Comment: @batFINGER Alright, done! Added more images to the post

Comment: Yep you have ngons.  Similar in a way to [this recent Q/A](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/104644/subdivision-surface-modifier-error)

Comment: Don't use booleans folks, prefer [proper topology](http://topologyguides.com) instead.

Comment: @batFINGER Yup! No doubt. The link didn't help much, though. Any solution?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Well yeah but I needed those holes, how could I do it without booleans?

Comment: Maybe rijig the question re the barrel and how to produce with good topo.

Comment: Sorry, what? So I should re-make the barrel? Sure thing, but how? Without the boolean modifier it seems pretty hard

Comment: @Dan Manually modelling it with proper topology. Have you checked the link? There even a [specific example](http://topologyguides.com/image/133528602155) exactly for this case

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Oh, I see! Thank you! I got it

Answer (score -1):

Try selecting your entire mesh in edit mode and hit [ctrl + n] to recalculate normals. This should fix the shading..

Comment: Already tried that like a million times, and it didn't work. These are not messy normal shadows, these are concave faces shadows